# get a parameter from database with query c#

Tags: c#, date-conversion

```
string s = "select idviagem from tbviagem where dia like '" + idatxt.Text + "'";
cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
```

I need the `idviagem` from the table `tbviagem` to put in `idviagem` from `tbpassageiro` (it's FK on `tbpassageiro`) , but i need the get `idviagem` from `idatxt.Text` it's a DateTime format, but doing the insert (look down) gives me the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'select idviagem from tbviagem where dia like '06/12/2018 00:00:00'' to data type int.'

but `idviagem` is a int, of course .

```
string q = "insert into tbpassageiro (nome,cc,fotocc,idviagem) values(@n,@cc,@p,@iv)";

cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);

con.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", data);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", nometxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cc", cctxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iv", s);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: If you're using parameters for your insert statement, why don't you do the same for your select statement to avoid sql injection issues?

Comment: i need the idviagem , is in other table

Answer (score 2):

You should never execute SQL statements like that but use parameters. You are using parameters for your second statement but not doing it for the first one.

Having said that, you are trying to use the query string s as the parameter value for @iv. Instead you should ExecuteScalar in first and use the result of it in second.

However, you can both get the idviagem value and do the insert in one single statement like this:

```
 string q = @"insert into tbpassageiro 
(nome,cc,fotocc,idviagem) 
select @n,@cc,@p,idViagem from tbviagem where dia like @dia";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", data);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", nometxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cc", cctxt.Text);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@dia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idatxt.Text;

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Note: I don't suggest using AddWithValue, prefer Add instead.

EDIT: For sampling with a Datetime dia field:

```
DateTime dt;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dia", SqlDbType.DateTime);
if (DateTime.TryParse(idatxt.Text, out dt))
{
    cmd.Parameters["@dia"].Value = dt;
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters["@dia"].Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

If idatxt is for getting a date\datetime value it would be much easier to use DateTimePicker to get a valid DateTime value.

Comment: string q = @"insert into tbpassageiro 
(nome,cc,fotocc,idviagem) 
select @n,@cc,@p,idViagem from tbviagem where dia like @dia";    something is wrong right here, right?  this is not inserting nothing in my database :\

Comment: @GuilhermeMonteiro, no there is nothing wrong there. It is perfectly fine and would insert one or more rows, provided there is not anything wrong on your part. A row may not be inserted, say if there is no matching row in tbviagem where dia = idatxt.Text. Or you may not have right to insert into tbpassageiro. Watch what error are you getting, if a row exists where dia = idatxt.Text etc.

Comment: Reading your question again, I noticed the error you have contains '06/12/2018 00:00:00'. That makes me suspect your dia is not a string but datetime (or date, datetime2) value. If that is the case, change type to SqlDbType.DateTime and Parse your idatxt.Text to a datetime value (using strings with datetime fields requires extra care and not suggested).

Comment: Hey @Cetin Basoz , i resolved this with LINQ , finally , thank for your sugestions , and yes, the problema was there, in the format DateTime, but i already resolved that, thank you anyway :D

Comment: @GuilhermeMonteiro, with LINQ :) Why wouldn't you just ask how to do that from the start and the answer would be LINQ. With LINQ you didn't use string for datetime field I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the query string `s` as the parameter value for `@iv` instead of the result of that query.

I suggest executing your command `cmd` and passing the result value to `@iv`:

```
string s = "select idviagem from tbviagem where dia like '" + idatxt.Text + "'";
cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);

con.Open();
Int32 resultValue = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

string q = "insert into tbpassageiro (nome,cc,fotocc,idviagem) values(@n,@cc,@p,@iv)";

cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", data);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", nometxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cc", cctxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iv", resultValue);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: It shouldn't be string if it is integer.

Comment: To be safe you should use Convert instead of direct casting to Int32 (this would however work when the backend is MS SQL server, other backends doesn't guarantee to return an Int32 for integer).

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'The object reference was not defined as an instance of an object.'

System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteScalar (...) returned null.

Comment: You might want to try to put %% signs around the value when using LIKE

Comment: 'The object reference was not defined as an instance of an object.' System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteScalar (...) returned null  i dont understand .... idviagem its a PK from tbidviagem , and its FK on tbpassageiro and is identity , but i dont think that's because that ...